# Ubuntu 10.04 - /etc/rc*.d disappeared?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

My  /etc/rc*.d have disappeared, and now apt-get install doesn't work.

Is this normal? How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't sound normal at all.  You may need to either restore from a recent backup, if you have one, or do a lot of work to actually fix things.  If those files are actually gone, then other things are probably broken as well, you may need to completely rebuild the system.

I would suggest trying to boot off a live-cd and see if you can see your files.